# Numpy array is modified globally by the function without return

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

When I use the function that doesn't return anything, the input parameters remain globally unchanged.

For example:

```
def func(var):
    var += 1

a = 0

for i in range(3):
    func(a)
    print(a)
```

logically results in

```
0
0
0
```

By it doesn't seem to work the same when the input is numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

def func(var):
    var += 1

a = np.zeros(3)  

for i in range(3):
    func(a)
    print(a)
```

Output:

```
[1. 1. 1.]
[2. 2. 2.]
[3. 3. 3.]
```

Thus, all modifications were applied to array globally, not inside the function. Why is it happening? And, more generally, are there any special rules on how to handle np arrays as functions input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Python, any value passed to a function is passed by object reference. So, in the first case, where you pass a number to your function, `var` is set to a reference to the object that reresents the number `1`. In Python, even numbers are objects. To icrement `var` in this case actually means to set it with a reference to the object that represents the number `1+1`, which is the object that represents `2`. Note that object that represents the number `1` is not changed. Within the function, it is replaced.

When you pass a numpy array to your function it is likewise passed in by object reference. Hence, `var` now holds a reference to your array `a`. Incrementing an array by `arr += 1` means to add `1` to each of its elements. Hence, the actual content of the object that `var` references has to change. However, `var` still references the same object are incrementation.

Take a look at the following code:

```
import numpy as np

def func(vals):
    print('Before inc: ', id(vals))
    vals += 1
    print('After inc: ', id(vals))
```

When you pass in a number literal, `vals` is set to a reference of the object representing the respective number. This object has a unique id, which you can return using the `id` function. After incrementation, `vals` is a reference to the object representing a number which is one greater the first one. You can verify that by calling `id` again after incrementation. So, the output of the above function is something like:

```
Before inc:  4351114480
After inc:  4351114512
```

Note that there are two different objects. When now pass in an numpy array like, the resulting ids are the same:

```
a = np.zeros(3)
func(a)

Before inc:  4496241408
After inc:  4496241408
```

If you want to modify an array inside of a function and don't want that the apply changes take effect outside of the function, you have to copy your array:

```
def func(vals):
    _vals = vals.copy()
    # doing stuff with `_vals` won't change the array passed to `vals`
```

Answer (score 0):

`+=` for `int` (and `float`, `str`, ...) creates a *new* value. Such types are known as *immutable*, because each individual object cannot be changed.

```
>>> i = 1
>>> id(i)
4550541072
>>> i += 1
>>> id(i)  # different id
4550541104
```

This means incrementing such a value *inside a function* creates a new value inside the function. Any references outside of the function are unaffected.

`+=` for `np.array` (and `list`, `Counter`, ...) modifies the *content*. Such types are known as *mutable*, because each individual object can be changed.

```
>>> l = [0, 1, 2, 3]
>>> id(l)
4585425088
>>> l += [4]
>>> id(l)
4585425088
```

This means incrementing such a value *inside a function* changes the value of the object visible inside *and* outside of the function. Any references inside and outside of the function point to the exact same object, and show its changed value.